# How to verify if a string contains at least two numbers in Talend?

Tags: java, talend, tmap, data-integration

Does anybody know how to verify if a string contains at least two numbers in Talend using the Tmap component?

Example: The string "46 W Street, New York, NY 10033" is true since I have "46" and "10033"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the var section : - Declare a variable called `checkNumber` that have type a `boolean`

That have as value

```
row1.YourString.matches(".*\\d.*") ? true : false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found how to do what you want, you can go to the java api link :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
here you can find the contains methode wich return a boolean if there are the characters.

Comment: i know but i'm trying to tell talend if the string contains at least two numeric values (no matter the value is it just has to be an integer)